# Как объединить 2 docx файла

Tags: php, docx

Пробовал объединить через вот это:
https://github.com/krustnic/DocxMerge
https://github.com/jupitern/docx

но судя по исходному коду, кто-то у кого-то украл, и оно не работает в конечном итоге

-----=====-----

Пытался сделать объединение через clsTbsZip

```
$zip = new clsTbsZip();
// Open the first document
$zip->Open('FILE');
$content1 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$zip->Close();
// Extract the content of the first document
$p = strpos($content1, '<w:body');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag <w:body> not found in document 1.");
$p = strpos($content1, '>', $p);
$content1 = substr($content1, $p+1);
$p = strpos($content1, '</w:body>');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document 1.");
$content1 = substr($content1, 0, $p);
// Insert into the second document
$zip->Open('FILE');
$content2 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$p = strpos($content2, '</w:body>');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document 2.");
$content2 = substr_replace($content2, $content1, $p, 0);
$zip->FileReplace('word/document.xml', $content2, TBSZIP_STRING);
// Save the merge into a third file
$zip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, 'merge.docx');
```

но в конечном счете, в одном из файлов теряются все стили и фото

-----=====-----

Пробовал брать PHPWord, подключать туда свой файл и добавлять нужную мне страницу (просто фото и текст)
Но, тот текст который я добавляю, добавляется в самый конец, а нужно в самое начало

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('FILE');
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('TEXT');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('file.docx');
```

-----=====-----

Пробовал OpenTBS, но так и не сумел объединить 2 файла DOCX

Есть варианты решения данной проблемы?)
Объединить 2 файла DOCX без потери стилей и фото

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если заглянуть в исходные тексты PhpWord, то можно обнаружить, что вот так можно добавить секцию в начало файла и заполнить ее нужными данными. Но, у меня, к сожалению, нарушаются параметры абзацев исходного файла. Впрочем, тоже самое происходит, если просто файл открыть и сохранить. что-то я видимо, упускаю

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('source.docx');
foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
    $section->setElementIndex($section->getElementIndex() + 1);
}
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$text = $section->addText('TEXT');
$section->setElementIndex(1);
$phpWord->sortSections(function($a,$b) { return $a->getElementIndex() - $b->getElementIndex(); } );
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('target.docx');
```

Comment: Вот,я до такого тоже доходил, но не понял как пользоваться сортировкой. Спасибо)

Comment: у меня файл, на котором я проверял от какого-то 11 ворда. Там развалились размеры картинок и абзацам странные левые отступы сделались. Понятно, где это поправить,но возможно, что особенность конкретной вордовой версии :)

Comment: Где поправить это?)

Comment: а у вас тоже разваливается? я сча нашел другой ворд, там все норм :) Но, где править сечас напишу

Comment: Иногда слетают некоторые фото при мердже(

Comment: про это не знаю. у меня все на месте, но с неправильными атрибутами - левый абзацный отступ, если он не 0, и размер картинок в pt  вместо px. Но и это зависит от версии

Comment: Но абзацы тоже слетели, но первый нет,второй да

Comment: Как исправить ситуацию с абзацами?)

Comment: \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paragraph.php в функции setStyleValue умножается на 720 - вот из-за этого у меня слетало. Если не умножать, все норм

Comment: Что-то так не и не смог найти как это сделать не через исходный код. SetStyle есть у секции, он ведет к функции с таким же названием, но делает для секции. параграф можно дать addText, но нужно ведь дать тому тексту который приходит. Думал это можно сделать через getElements, но нам нет setStyle

Comment: Кстати. мне не помогло то что умножает на 720, все равно абзац пропадает)

Comment: да можно просто в файле закоментировать умножение для начала :)